# Facebook Login Button using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, facebook-login

I am attempting to add the Facebook Login button to my website using the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Now, this button is displayed in a view. The view is loaded only when the user explicitly requests to login to the website.

I am using the HTML5 version. In Step 1, I am asked to include the Javascript SDK - I do this immediately after the  tag. This is located in the main page that contains the `ng-view` directive.

I place the code to render the login button inside the view. Problem is that if I navigate to the view by clicking on the login button in the main page, the view does not render the FB login button. However if I refresh the page (the one containing the login view), the button renders.

I have moved the code for the Javascript SDK into the login view too- both before the button is rendered and after but that also does not solve the problem. Only when refreshing the login view, the button is rendered.

So,
a) Either I need to know why this is happening and the solution or
b) Refresh in AngularJS; that is I need to know the AngularJS way to refresh the login view before it is rendered so that (I Hope) the login button gets rendered.

Comment: Please post a link to plunker/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because Facebook renders the whole page once to find its buttons and stuff.
You need to re-run parser after you load ngView.

Since you shall not do dom manipulation on the controller here is a directive version.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("fbLogin", function($rootScope) {
    return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        if (FB) {
            FB.XFBML.parse(iElement[0]);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!! I was struggling to demo this in a plunker and this is a saver! I did not want to create a directive so what I did was in the view that contained the div to render the FB login button, I added a `script` tag at the end of the view with the code `FB.XFBML.parse();` and that did the trick! Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a solution for Google Plus Login button? Same issue different social network though...

Comment: There should be manual parse, bootstrap function. It must be included in the documentation, you have to dig through it.